# Modification needs to be done in iptables in case of a bridge between two interfaces is implemented

Tags: shell-script, networking, iptables, network-interface

I have a machine with 2 NICs; eth0 and eth1. Each NIC has an assigned IP address and the traffic between them is controlled using the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

SAT_RECV="192.168.200.0/16"
NQ=9
OUT_IFACE="eth1"
CLIENTS_IFACE="eth0"

/sbin/iptables -I PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --syn -j TCP_OPTIMIZATION
/sbin/iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --syn -j TCP_OPTIMIZATION

iptables -t mangle -I TCP_OPTIMIZATION -i eth0 -s 192.168.200.0/24 -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num=9
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $SAT_RECV  -o $OUT_IFACE -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I TCP_OPTIMIZATION -i eth0 -s 192.168.200.0/24 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 6009
```

I want to make a bridge between eth0 and eth1 where my machine will be able to be put in between a WAN link without the need to reconfigure any existing source/destination IP and the iptables script above remains effective and does what is written for.

Is there any modification needs to be done in the script in case of a bridge between eth0 and eth1 is implemented?

Comment: @Nasha Please post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: Your script is using eth0 and eth1. You say you have two NICs—eth1 and eth2. Do you actually have three, eth0, eth1, and eth2?

Comment: Done your honour.

Comment: @derobert Sorry it was a typo, I have fixed it.

Comment: @derobert : see why I don't rush to post as answers?

Comment: @Nasha Sorry about that! Normally that's not how it works out. Often it's browse unanswered questions, find out a bunch actually are answered... just not as an answer. If you're not answering because the question is unclear, you ought to beat me to adding a comment requesting clarification :-P

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This answer is no longer valid.

<strike>Just replace *eth1* with the bridge interface name, e.g. *br0* typically. Preferably *eth1* and *eth2* should be on separate segments. Otherwise you'll have to enable [STP](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#Spanning_Tree_Protocol).</strike>

Comment: I have edited the question to have only `eth0` and `eth1`, do I still need to replace `eth1` by `br0` or `eth0` by `br0`? What do you mean by <separate segments>, different network IP?

Comment: Well, that changes *everything* and my answer is no longer valid for that use case. From my understanding of what you're trying to do, you need at least *three* interfaces, two of them which are bridge members and one for the WAN connection. With a bridge it's as if there were only one [logical] interface with an IP address. So please expose in your question all the interfaces you have along with their IP addresses so we have a clear idea of what can be done.

Comment: A [segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment) is an electrical connection between networked devices with layer 2 forwarding hence does not involve TCP/IP. If you have redundant bridges on the same network then you *must* enable STP to prevent traffic loops.

Comment: I have in my machine 2 physical network interfaces `eth0` & `eth1`, what exactly I am looking for is to make my machine works as plug and plays in between a link which connecting my company head quarter with a remote branch therefore I tried to bridge the two physical interface with keeping iptables does its job descried in the script above.

Comment: I'd suggest you edited your question and added a scheme including the permanent interfaces along with the temporary ones. Also indicate, which is a VPN (if at all), what interface and IP addresses it provides. What you want is complex enough to justify an exhaustive picture of the full context. Besides I don't see how your script would fit if both interfaces it references are bridged. It's still quite unclear what "your company head quarter" network is and how you connect to it. Is it through OpenVPN? PoPToP? Cisco VPN? Direct link? We really need a detailed picture.